# C# code analysis output on working project, warnings list advice requested

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, warnings, analysis

I recently finished the first part of a C# project, windows forms application, all works fine, it’s just when I run code analysis, (visual studio 2015), is throws up lots of warnings.

Questions:

1. Why are these warnings not shown on normal debugging?
2. Is it advisable to spend, (what would be a lot), of time solving these warnings? and why as the project works?
3. If question 2 is true, is there a quick reference document, that can assist in the many warnings and there meanings?

I went through microsoft documentation, but very time comsuming.

Comment: #1 - there's not enough information in your post to let us know _what_ warnings are/are not being displayed, or what analysis tool you're using. #2 - opinion based question. #3 - it depends on which tool you're using, but a google search for ID number usually helps. Either way, that's asking for an off-site resource. See [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: @gunr2171, I am not asking for there VS15 Code analysis meanings, more can I ignore them as project is working, and if I should not ignore them why, I am not asking for opinions I am asking for facts

Comment: Code analysis is about best practice. Your code can work fine without implementing best practice, but it won't be the best code it can be. You should heed those warnings now so you can start writing better code now and thus have fewer warnings in the future. That will also minimise the possibility of hard-to-find bugs in your code too.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thankyou for your input, answers question 2, question 3 has been anwered in other comments, but alas a newbe gets the tick as answered all I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If by "code analysis" you mean the Error List window, which has three tabs for Errors, Warnings, and Messages, your program will indeed run if there are only Warnings and Messages, but there could be problems for you down the road. "Messages" are almost always stylistic suggestions (like a variable that VS thinks should be private, or an unused function), but Warnings are typically a sign that something COULD go wrong at runtime (such as neglecting to initialize a variable). The Error List window won't typically show up if there are no errors, but VS settings do control some of that behavior.
2. How much time you should spend addressing the warnings depends on how much time you want to spend chasing runtime errors. I could care less about the "Messages", but my goal is always to have zero Warnings.
3. I always just Google the Error or Warning ID, if the text description doesn't make any sense, and some Microsoft support site usually comes up... or even StackOverflow, with some good advice on how to fix it. You can suppress Warnings in code or VS settings, but that's only a last resort, if you realize you can't fix it, it's not an issue long-term, and you don't want to see it anymore.